# Office 365 Message Encryption and EWS API endpoints

Tags: office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

If a Exchange 365 user uses  [Office 365 Message Encryption (OME)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-365-Message-Encryption-OME-f87cb016-7876-4317-ae3c-9169b311ff8a) to send and receive encrypted emails, can these emails and their header information be read by using the EWS API endpoints?

**Update/Clarification**

We are mainly interested in being able to read the Email Headers of a mail that was sent/received using Office 365 Message Encryption (OME). So things like `From`, `To`, `CC`, `SentDate`, `Subject` etc. Will these headers be available to be accessed via the EWS API.
It is not a requirement for us to actually be able to decrypt and read the actual contents of the mail.

NOTE: we would be using `ApplicationImpersonation` to access mailboxes on behalf of users and read the email headers in each mailbox.

Comment: You probably should clarify what did you mean by "emails and their header information be read". Do you want to get decrypted message or SMIME BLOB? And I assume "headers" are internet transport headers, right?

Comment: The email headers that we are mainly interested in are things from From, To, CC, SentDate, Subject etc.  - I'll update the question to clarify this

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Microsoft documentation [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Email-encryption-in-Office-365-c0d87cbe-6d65-4c03-88ad-5216ea5564e8):

> A message is encrypted, or transformed from plain text into unreadable
>   ciphertext, either on the sender’s machine, or by a central server
>   while the message is in transit.

and the following [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn569285.aspx):

> Are Office 365 encrypted messages stored in the cloud or on Microsoft
>   servers?
>
> No, the encrypted messages are kept on the recipient’s email system,
>   and when the recipient opens the message, it is temporarily posted for
>   viewing on Office 365 servers. The messages are not stored there.

and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn569285.aspx):

> Can I read the encrypted messages over mobile devices?
>
> Yes, you can view messages on Android and iOS by downloading the OME
>   Viewer apps from the Google Play store and the Apple App store. Open
>   the HTML attachment in the OME Viewer app and then follow the
>   instructions to open your encrypted message. For other mobile devices,
>   you can open the HTML attachment as long as your mail client supports
>   Form Post.

and the following [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Email-encryption-in-Office-365-c0d87cbe-6d65-4c03-88ad-5216ea5564e8):

> To view encrypted messages, recipients can either get a one-time
>   passcode, sign in with a Microsoft account, or sign in with a work or
>   school account associated with Office 365.

and this [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/compilations/2014/04/29/office-365-message-encryption-decryption-steps-for-purchase-configuration-branding-and-use-everything-you-need-to-know/#.Wh13hHko-JA):

```
Encrypted messages can be viewed on any client device, as long as the HTML attachment can be opened in a modern browser that supports Form Post.
```

and important this [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-365-Protected-Message-Viewer-Portal-privacy-statement-05b2e7e4-230e-48a9-802c-4cafac0d7c9d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US):

> During the decryption process, the encrypted mail you receive will not
>   be stored by the Portal; it will not be transmitted outside the Portal
>   at any time.

I would say that there is no option to use EWS to read such emails as that would be totally against what Microsoft wrote above. Because then the Administrator can bypass the encryption which isn´t possible without having the users password. So I would assume that EWS has the same restrictions as an Administrator and therefore isn´t able to perform that.

However as Office 365 Message Encryption uses Rights Management Services (RMS) as its encryption infrastructure (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn569285.aspx)) you might wish to check what you can build on RMS.

Comment: While your answer is solid proof by the docs, I believe what OP is asked is if it is possible to read with EWS API headers and content of SMIME. The transport headers are definitely available from  `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS`, which is  `0x007D` tag id. The content (SMIME BLOB) may be available as well from `<t:MimeContent>`, but am not sure about that. You right to open up this BLOB, you need private key, but may be OP has it as of server side scanning solution, something like master key.

Comment: Yes but the issue is that  Office 365 Message Encryption (OME) is used as written by the OP and not S/Mime. Both are different products... with S/Mime that would be easy as it is using certificates and you would be totally right. However OME is not using certificates and therefore any approach in that direction wouldn´t work. With OME there would be an encrypted attachment in every email and you can click on that attachment and decrypt that attachment in your web browser which send a connection to Office 365. Via that way it works from everywhere also for non Office 365 user.

Comment: Sure, I missed the point of OEM (RMS) messages. For those types of messages you should be able to get the headers anyway with EWS by using `InternetHeaders` extended property. For example: [Finding RMS Items in a Mailbox using EWS](http://gsexdev.blogspot.ca/2015/12/finding-rms-items-in-mailbox-using-ews.html). Requested by OP "To", "Cc", etc. headers will be inside this property. As I mention before I don't know about the content, but as OP clarified he doesn't rely need it.

Answer (score 0):

This is in detail explained by two pieces of Microsoft documentation: [[MS-OXORMMS]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463909.aspx) and [[MS-RMPR]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc243191.aspx).

The basic idea is that the encrypted part of the message is transferred as an attachment, while the unencrypted body only contains a convenience link for a client not supporting OME to allow reading the message.

The actual attachment is encrypted using a key on the server. To retrieve it you have to activate against the Rights Management Server and retrieve a license to decrypt the message.

Sending works the opposite way - you encrypt the message, send the key to the server and send the encrypted message as attachment to Exchange.

Based on that I think it is possible to send and receive OME-encrypted messages using EWS, as long as the client implements the necessary encrption/decryption/license management.